# how to replace current_date() to any date type by user

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

how to replace current_date()  to any date type by user

example:

www.example.com/2025-01-04

or any date

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "11_11";
$password = "1Eh]V";
$dbname = "1_1";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT domain FROM insights_base WHERE domain_1 = current_date() ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$data = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $data[] = $row;
    }
}
$conn->close();

$smarty = new Smarty;
$smarty->assign('data', $data);
$smarty->display(APP_THEME . '/dom.tpl');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "11_11";
$password = "1Eh]V";
$dbname = "1_1";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
if (isset($_GET['date'])
    and preg_match('/^\d{4}(-\d{2}){2}$/', $_GET['date']) // primitive validation
) {
    $date = $_GET['date'];
} else {
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
}
$sql = "SELECT domain FROM insights_base WHERE domain_1 = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $date);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($domain);
$data = array();
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
   $data[] = array('domain' => $domain);
}
$conn->close();

$smarty = new Smarty;
$smarty->assign('data', $data);
$smarty->display(APP_THEME . '/dom.tpl');
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in /home/111/public_html/file.php on line 22 - See more at: http://www.11.com/folder/2015-06-07

Comment: It can occurs when you add new fields to `select` clause and don't add it to `bind_result`, for example: `SELECT domain, domain_1 FROM insights_base` and `$stmt->bind_result($domain, $domain_1);`, it should work...

Comment: Now working
But
I want to be a visitor to enter the date and changed the results by date
Example
www.example.com/1999-01-04
Or
www.example.com/2015-05-06

Comment: It's easy) The more convenient way - `www.example.com?date=2015-05-06` and in code write `$stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['date']);` instead `$stmt->bind_param('s', $date);`. And don't forget validate this variable...

Comment: thanks Vladimir Kovpak & how to display current date in index page example www.example.com/currentdate and display  get date any date www.example.com?date=2015-05-06

Comment: hello Vladimir , how to add any date in title page <title>page 2015-05-06  </title> or any date

Comment: hi!)  `<title>page {$date} </title>`

Comment: Try `{$smarty.get.date}`.

Comment: It does not work in the main area
But within the page works well

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a prepared statement here (assuming you are using mysqli).
**A)** Because you can dynamically assign either `current_date()` or variable using user input value to a placeholder.
**B)** The prepared statement would make this operation more secure since you are escaping all user input.

```
if (!empty($_POST['date'])) {
    $user_date = $_POST['date'];
} else {
    $user_date = "current_date()";
}

$sql = "SELECT domain FROM insights_base WHERE domain_1 = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $user_date);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$data = [];
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $data[] = $row;
    }
}
```

Depending on how you are getting the date from user, you may need to validate it to make sure that it is in the proper date/time format for mysql.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$stmt' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/111/public_html/file.php on line 25

Comment: @MuhamedRadwan - Sorry, had a syntax error. Fixed now.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in /home/1111/public_html/file.php on line 32

Comment: hmmm...looks like you don't have the needed driver for that, you can use `fetch` instead.